# Angular : Relative navigation on a named router outlet

Tags: angular, router-outlet, angular-router

I have the following **Angular Route** configuration

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: DirectoryComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'manage/:type/:id',
      component: ManageComponent,
      outlet: 'manage',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          component: PreviewComponent,
          pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
          path: 'add/:elementType',
          component: EditComponent,
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

`ManageComponent` is a sandbox component in which `PreviewComponent` and `EditComponent` will be rendered.

An user use case redirect the user to `http://localhost:4200/#/(manage:manage/bar/12762)` which match the preview component. Everything is okay here.

From the `PreviewComponent` and when the user clicks on a button, I want to make a relative navigation to the `EditComponent` to have, when the navigation finish, `http://localhost:4200/#/(manage:manage/bar/12762/add/foo)`

I tried

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: {manage: ['add', 'foo']}}],{relativeTo: this.route});
```

and

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: {manage: ['add', 'foo']}}]);
```

But every time, user is redirected to `http://localhost:4200/#/add/foo`.

#### How can I please make this navigation ?

Comment: Having the same problem, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: No I didn't succeed to implement the relative navigation. I workaround it by building manually the URL and navigate to it using `navigateByUrl` router method.

Answer (score 4):

I know that it's an old question, but I found a solution while I'm looking for an answer.

You can use `{ relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent }` and everything works like a charm.